# I have a polygon with 0 altitude but on map the data has a height

Tags: google-maps, kml

I'm creating polygons with a certain lat, lon, and altitude of 0. I want to just have points right on the ground with 0 height to them. I'm using relative to ground, for the altitude mode. the extrude =1. tesselate =0 . Is it possible to do this??? Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this google-maps, but I'm going to assume you mean Google Earth, since there's no altitude in Google Maps, which is 2D. If I understand your question correctly, you want to have a polygon that is right on the ground. Have you tried altitudeMode of clampToGround instead?